# How to send emails using godaddy office365 in dotnet core?

Tags: .net-core, smtp, office365

each time I try to send an email using my SMTP credentials from godaddy mail, I get this error message, even if I'm authenticated

```
The SMTP server requires a secure connection or the client was not authenticated. The server response was: 5.7.57 SMTP; Client was not authenticated to send anonymous
mail during MAIL FROM [YQBPR0101CA0107.CANPRD01.PROD.OUTLOOK.COM]
```

here's the code I've been using to send emails:

```cs
var client = new SmtpClient(
    config.GetValue<string>("EmailSettings:MailServer"), 
    config.GetValue<int>("EmailSettings:MailPort")) 
{
    UseDefaultCredentials = false,
    Credentials = new NetworkCredential(config.GetValue<string>("EmailSettings:Sender"), config.GetValue<string>("EmailSettings:Password")),
    TargetName = config.GetValue<string>("EmailSettings:TargetName"),
    EnableSsl = config.GetValue<bool>("EmailSettings:EnableSSL"),
    DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network,
};

try
{
    return client.SendMailAsync(
        new MailMessage(
            from: config.GetValue<string>("EmailSettings:Sender"), 
            to: email, 
            subject: subject, 
            body: htmlMessage) 
        {
            IsBodyHtml = isBodyHtml,
            BodyEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8,
            SubjectEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8,
        }
    );
}
catch(Exception exception)
{
    client.Dispose();
    throw exception;
}
```

I added a new section in my `appsettings.json` to provide the configuration

```json
"EmailSettings": {
  "MailServer": "smtp.office365.com",
  "MailPort": 587,
  "Sender": "user@mydomain.ca",
  "Password": "Passw0rd!",
  "EnableSSL": true,
  "TargetName": "STARTTLS/smtp.office365.com"
}
```

What could cause this issue if I'm properly authenticated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just like most SMTP providers, there's restrictions in the authentication for sending outgoing mail from an anonymous authenticated computer, since godaddy use it's own re****** version of the office365 administration panel, you simply can't change this setting. You have to call godaddy's customer service, and hope that after an hour of waiting, that the representative will actually know what you are talking about before hanging off on you.